# What is this aircraft that has flown over my house all day?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I mainly joined to ask this question. I would not have been so curious had it not flown directly over my house at least 5 times in about a half-hour. Every time my house started rumbling, I’d rush outside to snap some pictures before it was too far gone. Any help would be appreciated - especially if anyone knows why it came across so frequently.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wish i had a house under some c17s

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate. One cannot search based on just an image on SE, you can only search text. Given that a person asking to identify an aircraft inherently does not know the name of the aircraft, how can they be expected to find a previous post asking about a C-17?

Comment: @zymhan: And that is why humans are involved, and not a search robot (note that OP agreed it solved their question). The other extreme is having 10 distinct questions for the same aircraft-identification, say a 747 – does not make it right.

Comment: If you want to know why it's flying over your house, it would help if we knew where your house is located :-)

Comment: Discuss on meta: [Are 'aircraft identification' questions using photos eligible for duplicate voting?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3770/14897)

Answer (score 5):

[Looks to me like a Boeing C-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-17_Globemaster_III), if you live near a military base or airport that may explain it.

[image]

Comment: Beat me to the punch.  It is indeed a C-17 Globemaster.

Comment: As its gear is down, it's likely flying circuits, short flights, or touch and go landings at a nearby airfield.

Comment: Thanks all! Very interesting. I did some research and they first started in Charleston, SC. Makes sense since I live in South Carolina.